# Parsing dates with dart

Tags: parsing, date, datetime, dart

I need to parse this kind of date "Mon, 11 Aug 2014 12:53 pm PDT" in a [`DateTime`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.DateTime) object in Dart.

The `DateTime` has a static method [`parse`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.DateTime#id_parse) that accepts a subset of ISO 8601 format, not my case.

The [`DateFormat`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/intl/intl.DateFormat) class lets you define the date pattern to parse. I've created the pattern "EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a zzz".

Using it I get a `FormatException: Trying to read a from Mon, 11 Aug 2014 12:53 pm PDT at position 23`.

Looks like the parser does not like the PM marker case (I've open an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=20453) about).

I've tried to workaround the issue upper casing the entire string. With the string all upper case I get again a FormatException due to the week day and the month names in upper case.

Any other solution or workaround?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can just replace the lowercase 'am'/'pm' characters by uppercase.

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  var date = 'Mon, 11 Aug 2014 12:53 pm PDT';
  DateFormat format = new DateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a zzz");
  date = date.replaceFirst(' pm', ' PM').replaceFirst(' am', ' AM');
  print(date);
  print(format.parse(date));
}
```

Comment: But note that the time zone is not parsed. Neither DateFormat nor DateTime is time zone aware.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, didn't notice.

Answer (score 4):

Try this package, [Jiffy](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy). It handles all of the parsing, no need to upper case your string

```
var jiffy = Jiffy.parse("Mon, 11 Aug 2014 12:53 pm PDT", pattern: "EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a zzz");
```

You can also format it and manipulate dateTime easily. Example

```
jiffy.format("dd MM yyyy");
// Or use DateFormat's default date time formats
jiffy.yMMMM;
// Also get relative time
jiffy.fromNow();
```